# How to read a line from the file inside a for loop

Tags: rust

How to read a line from the file inside a for loop? I have a file `Movies.txt` inside which each movie entry has 2 properties namely `name` and `rating` which I would like to read. In C I could write like below

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void read_file() {
    FILE* movies = fopen("Movies.txt", "r");
    if (movies == nullptr) {
        perror("Error opening Movies.txt\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // contains only 4 entries as of now
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        char name[1024]{};
        if (fscanf(movies, "%*[^=]=%s", name) == EOF) {
            perror("Error in reading Movies.txt");
            printf("in \"%s: %s\" at line %d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        float rating{};    
        if (fscanf(movies, "%*[^=]=%f", &rating) == EOF) {
            perror("Error in reading Movies.txt");
            printf("in \"%s: %s\" at line %d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Movie Name: %s\tRating: %f", name, rating);
    }

    fclose(movies);
}

int main() {
    read_file();
}
```

How to achieve the same in Rust. This is my attempt

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use regex::Regex;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn read_file() {
    let file = File::open("Movies.txt");
    let buff_reader;
    match file {
        Ok(mut file) => buff_reader = BufReader::new(file),
        _err => return,
    }

    for (_, line) in buff_reader.lines().enumerate() {
        for i in [0..4] {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            let reg_ex = Regex::new(r"^[^=]+\s*=\s*(?<name>\w+)$").unwrap();
            let Some(caps) = reg_ex.captures(&line) else {
                println!("no match!");
                return;
            };
            
            // want to read next line... but how?
            // let line = line.unwrap();
            // let reg_ex = Regex::new(r"^[^=]+\s*=\s*(?<rating>\w+)$").unwrap();
            // let Some(caps) = reg_ex.captures(&line) else {
            //     println!("no match!");
            //     return;
            // };
            // println!("Movie Name: {}\tRating: {}", name, rating);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    read_file();
}
```

Movies.txt

```
Movie name: Harry Potter1
rating: 8.5
Movie name: Harry Potter2
rating: 9.5
Movie name: Harry Potter3
rating: 8
Movie name: Harry Potter4
rating: 8
```

Comment: Please provide the example input file. -- While you're [edit]ing your question, you might want to correct an apparent error: the iterator returned by `enumerate()` already separates the lines. The additional loop (0 to 3) makes no sense. -- And since you throw away the index, you can as well remove `enumerate()` and use the iterator `lines()` directly. -- A common way to develop is to incrementally build your program. Start with a simple `dbg!(line);` in the `for` loop.

Comment: what is the exact error here in the question, i cant see a proper error description?

Comment: I think I can make use of `read_line` method of `BufRead` trait. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line

Comment: @Harry Please show us the `Movies.txt` file. Just from your code, the expected format is not very clear.

Comment: he needs the code how to do that in rust

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file contains pairs of lines, I would simply extract each line and alternatively consider it as the name of the movie, or the value of the rating.
In both cases, the relevant piece of information stands after the `:` symbol; we just have to split the line on this symbol (the prefix does not matter so much...) and trim the surrounding whitespaces.

At every step, we have to consider the potential errors and report them explicitly (in order to ease file format error detection) .
I chose here to use `Box<dyn Error>` in order to provide any kind of error thanks to the `?` operator.

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
};

fn read_movies_and_rating(
    path: &str
) -> Result<Vec<(String, f32)>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut name = None;
    let input = BufReader::new(File::open(path)?);
    for (i, line) in input.lines().enumerate() {
        match line {
            Ok(line) => {
                // the relevant information is after ':'
                if let Some((_left, right)) = line.split_once(':') {
                    if i % 2 == 0 {
                        // this line contains the name
                        name = Some(right.trim().to_owned());
                    } else {
                        // this line contains the value
                        match right.trim().parse() {
                            Ok(value) => {
                                result.push((name.take().unwrap(), value))
                            }
                            Err(e) => Err(format!(
                                "{:?} line {}: invalid value {:?}: {}",
                                path,
                                i + 1,
                                right,
                                e
                            ))?,
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Err(format!(
                        "{:?} line {}: invalid line: {}",
                        path,
                        i + 1,
                        line
                    ))?
                }
            }
            Err(e) => Err(format!(
                "{:?} line {}: invalid line: {}",
                path,
                i + 1,
                e
            ))?,
        }
    }
    if let Some(name) = name {
        Err(format!(
            "{:?}: last movie {:?} does not have any rating",
            path, name
        ))?
    }
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() {
    match read_movies_and_rating("Movies.txt") {
        Ok(result) => {
            for (name, value) in result.iter() {
                println!("{:?} ~~> {}", name, value);
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error: {}", e);
        }
    }
}
/*
"Harry Potter1" ~~> 8.5
"Harry Potter2" ~~> 9.5
"Harry Potter3" ~~> 8
"Harry Potter4" ~~> 8
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the lines into a collection, then use [chunks_exact](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact) to loop every 2 lines.

Here an example I'm just using a string and overkilling it with trim, and use [trim_start_matches](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_start_matches) on each line to get the actual name and rating but you can use regex or any method of extraction.

```
fn main() {
    
    let movies_string  = r"
        Movie name: Harry Potter1
        rating: 8.5
        Movie name: Harry Potter2
        rating: 9.5
        Movie name: Harry Potter3
        rating: 8
        Movie name: Harry Potter4
        rating: 8
        Movie name: Harry Potter No Rating
        rating: bah
        Movie name: Harry Potter No No No
    ";

    let mut movies = Vec::new();

    //just replace this with your file BufRead 
    let lines: Vec<&str> = movies_string.trim().lines().collect();

    for chunk in lines.chunks_exact(2) {
        if chunk.len() == 2 {
            //every 1st line
            let name = chunk[0].trim().trim_start_matches("Movie name:").trim();

            //every 2nd line
            let rating = chunk[1].trim().trim_start_matches("rating:").trim();
            
            //parse maybe
            let rating_maybe = rating.parse::<f32>().unwrap_or(0.0);

            movies.push((name.to_string(), rating_maybe));
        }
    }


    println!("movie lists: {:#?}", movies);
}
```